# Can I Identify The Environment Using HTML Code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I just figured out how to create custom error pages in the public folder using I18n.  Those error pages have links that will return the user to a page in the application such as the home page.

When my application was running 3.2.13 I had the custom error pages in the app folder using `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` in application.rb.  When I had that code all I had to do was use a link_to statement pointing to the route I wanted the user to return to.  If I was in the development environment it would go to `http://localhost:3000/somelink` and in production it would go to `http://myrailsapp.com/somelink`.  I replaced these with the ones in the public folder after rewriting them in Rails 4 because it appears that `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` is ignored in Rails 4.

My error pages in the public folder are html, not html.erb so there is no ruby/rails code.  I would like to replicate what I had previously where I can check the environment in my error pages and point to localhost for development or my domain URL for production.  I currently have code in my error page similar to this:

```
<a href="http://myrailsapp.com/en/home">My Link Text</a>
```

I'm definitely open to changing these to html.erb files.  I initially thought about that but from my research and trying what I found nothing is working for Rails 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you be more precise?

Comment: can't you use relativa paths, not urls? Just change `http://myrailsapp.com/en/home` to `/en/home`

Comment: Almaron, your response worked.  I was forgetting the slash which caused errors.  Thanks so much.  I have changed all my error pages :)

Comment: @Almaron, please add your solution as an answer and I will check it.  In my Rails 3 applications I did not have the beginning slash and things worked fine.  When I upgraded to Rails 4 nothing was found.  Now I know the beginning slash is require in Rails 4 with HTML5 code.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @LightBeCorp glad to help) don't forget to upvote good answers besides accepting them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any "autodetection" in html, just cut the domain part from the url and use a local path instead.

Just change `http://myrailsapp.com/en/home` to `/en/home`.

And yes, you do need the opening slash to be independent from the current_url in your link.